# angular ngMessages custom validation ng-message

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I've got this custom validation

```
function uiEmailEquals() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.uiEmailEquals, function() {
        ngModel.$validate();
      });
      ngModel.$validators.isEquals = function(value) {
        var email = scope.$eval(attrs.uiEmailEquals);
        if (!email || !value) {
          return false;
        }
        return (value === email);
      };
    }
  };
}

<input type="email" tabindex="4" name="cemail" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.data.cemail" placeholder="confirm email" ng-required="true" ui-email-equals="vm.data.email"
/>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.cemail.$error" ng-if="form.cemail.$touched">
    <p class="error-message" ng-message="required">Required</p>
    <p class="error-message" ng-message="email">Not valid email</p>
    <p class="error-message" ng-message="uiemailequals">uiemailequals</p>
    <p class="error-message" ng-message="ui-email-equals">ui-email-equals</p>
    <p class="error-message" ng-message="uiEmailEquals">uiEmailEquals</p>
    <p class="error-message" ng-message="equals">equals</p>
</div>
```

The problem is I don't find the exp to set inside

**ng-message**

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: ngModel.$validators.isEquals - this is the name of your custom validator -> isEquals -> <p class="error-message" ng-message="isEquals">is equals</p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngModel.$validators.isEquals` - this is the name of your custom validator -> isEquals

```
<p class="error-message" ng-message="isEquals">is equals</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

method name is `isEquals` use `ng-message="isEquals"`