# ng-messages compare two numbers

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I want to compare two numbers in a form and display an error with ng-messages.

my html code :

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>min</label>
    <input name="valMin" type="number" ng-model="valMin" />
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container>
    To
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container>
    <label>max</label>
    <input name="valMax" type="number" ng-model="valMax" />
    <div ng-messages="myForm.valMax.$error" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="compare">Max value must be greater than min value.</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

compare doesn't exists. I have seen this post :

[angular ngMessages custom validation ng-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015743/angular-ngmessages-custom-validation-ng-message)

Is this the good way to do my custom validation or is there a better method ?

thanks

Comment: Where is logic for compare ?

Comment: like i said "compare" doesn't exists with ng-messages -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages

Answer (score 0):

Try like  :

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.valMax.$error" role="alert" ng-show="!(valMax > valMin)">
    <div ng-message="compare">Max value must be greater than min value.</div>
</div>
```